# ExtJs Add Json Data

Tags: extjs

I am facing problem in **ExtJs**. `OnClick` function it should load data for one time. But it is replicating the same data on every click.

Here is my code:

```
function onselectionchange() 
{

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Maintainer/getfolders",
    data: null,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: true,
    success: function (result) {
        var store = Ext.getCmp('gridpanel').getStore();
        store.loadData(result, true);
    },

    error: function (p_Result) {
        var error = "Error  on controller: \"" + p_Controller + "\" in function: \"" + p_ControllerFunction + "\" statusText: \"" + p_Result.statusText;
        alert(error);
    },
    traditional: true
});

}
```

Comment: You're posting the same data (actually no data) to the same url each time.  Why would you expect different output?

Comment: The data is provided by the URL which is further stored in the result.  The function is invoked by grid.OnClickFunction. It is working fine when I click the data is displayed but when I click again the same data is replicating on every click. I want click function should work for one time only. If possible please help me out.                                                                                                                                                                                                          grid.OnClickFunction = "onselectionchange()";

Comment: do you want the action to happen the first time a single row is clicked, or only one time overall.

Comment: Yes, when I click first row the action should happen but when I click again the same row there should be no action.

Comment: Why do you mix ExtJs and jQuery ? If you use ExtJs for data or user interface, you should use it also for ajax requests. ExtJs will read the data, update the store and the UI all automatically for you.

Comment: I cannot immagine any reason why you would want to use both frameworks together. The only guarantee is to get unmaintainable and inconsistent code. And a slow page load.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onselectionchange() 
    {
    if(clickonce == "")
    {
    ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/url",
        data: null,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {

        enter code here
        clickonce = 1;
        }

    });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("already selected once");
    } 
    }
```

What i'am doing here is creating a global variable with clickonce. When you first click on the button the json will get uploaded and the flag on this variable will set to 1 hence it won't be populated again.